# What is the reason for the thing you get in Stiltons manor to pulsate?

Tags: dishonored-2

After you're finished in the Dust District you come to Aramis Stiltons Manor and get the

> Timepiece.

I noticed it pulsating in the same manner as the heart does when you look in the direction of a rune or bonecharm, but I wasn't able to deduct what caused this.

Is there a specific reasoning to it?

Comment: I think it points to runes or charms in the other timeline.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a documented reason for it. I don't recall noticing the behavior myself though.

It's possible it's simply a bug, but one could speculate on a lore-based reason: it's a device of the Void or of the Outsider, like the heart, and is thus attuned to the same sort of energies, those that runes and charms give off. It could thus be expected to react in a similar fashion when in the presence of such artifacts.

Comment: I switched between the thing and heart on several occasions while pointing at runes/bonecharms and only the heart was pulsating so it's not that. I will try to narrow it down when playing the second time and come back to accept your answer should I not find something myself.

Comment: @vanillagod the runes/charms are split between the time periods. If the heart can only see the current ones, perhaps the timepiece reacts to the other ones.